# Looking for name of a short story about time machine research funded by Native Americans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Short story: A grad student(?) is building a viewer that can look back in time. The project (on a shoestring budget) is funded by a Native American tribe, and several elders visit for a demo of the machine, but they are disappointed and ask the researcher to drive them to bingo. Finally the machine works and the elders are shown one of their ancestors fishing in a pristine stream. They are sad and wish they had not seen this irretrievable bit of the past.

I really liked the writer's characters - both the researcher and the elders were portrayed quite realistically and with humor.

I read this story in the last 2-3 years in an anthology, but it could have been an old one. I thought it might have been a Twelve Tomorrows anthology from MIT but I can't find it in those.

Comment: The Battle of Little Big Science is it - many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The Battle of Little Big Science](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1130801) by Pamela Rentz. I read it in the August 2010 edition of Asimov's Science Fiction, but is has been collected in a couple of anthologies as well. Possibly you read it in Rentz's 2012 short story collection [Red Tape: Stories from Indian Country](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?459146).

The fishing scene you remember is at the end of the story:

> “Good. I've saved the best for last.” She adjusted the controller. Once again the view faded and they moved. This time, the roar of the falls vibrated under the viewing mat before they could see the wall of cascading white water that burst over a half-circle of huge basalt boulders. The breeze carried a cool mist with it. The blue water of the river stretched out into the far distance.

But it turns out that was a sad memory because:

> “Why did you show us something so sad?” Maisie rubbed Ramona's back, her face twisted with concern.
>
> Agnes didn't know what to say.
>
> Ramona sat up. “We was there when they made that dam. The government promised us that fishing place and then gave my father three thousand dollars and filled it up with water.”
>
> “I know,” Agnes said. “Wasn't it amazing to see it before it was destroyed?”
>
> “He nailed that check to the wall. He didn't want their money.” Tears ran down Ramona's cheeks and she pulled a rumpled tissue from her sleeve.